# Removing for loops with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

So the idea is i'm trying to remove  a for loop in python with Numpy

```
return np.array([points[closest==k].mean(axis=0) for k in range(k)])
```

Where points is an array of points in my case 2d points. Closest is a labeling array keeping track of labes for each point in points. K is just a number

So my idea is if i created an array that was 3 dimensional that was split for each k, then i could just take mean of that array without doing the for loop.

If you have an idea of a better idea, feel free to share :)

Comment: Perhaps you could post a sample input and expected output so what your trying to do is clearer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html):

```
import scipy.stats

# ...
    return scipy.stats.binned_statistic(closest, points.T, np.arange(k + 1)).statistic
```